# Angular 6 multiple library cross-dependency

Tags: angular, shared-libraries, angular6

I have installed multiple libraries in angular 6 and I need to import one library in another. They depend on each other but it's not working

Here's how it goes:

`ng generate library lib1`

`ng generate library lib2`

Now in the main application, in `package.json` I add to `tsconfig.json` in `compilerOptions` the libraries (they are automatically inserted)

`"paths": {
   "lib1": ["../distPack/lib1"],
   "lib2": ["../distPack/lib2"]
}`

(I modified the path where they are generated to be `distPack`)

I can import them in `app.module` and everything works fine

`import { Lib1Module } from 'lib1'`

**PROBLEM**

I want to:
`import { Lib1Module } from 'lib1'` in `lib2/src/lib/lib2.module.ts`

And and it can't find it.

What I tried:

1. `peerDependency`
2. adding it to `tsconfig.lib` as `paths`
3. including it as direct path (fails in --prod build)

**Update**

If I build the set the paths  in main `tsconfig.json` to

`"paths": {
      "lib1": [
        "dist/lib1"
      ],`

the other libraries can import it without a problem **BUT** it can no longer be imported in `app.module`

Comment: not sure if this helps, but I believe that you should list the lib1's dependency on lib2 as a peerDependency, and also have the library paths in tsconfig.json

Comment: I tried that, doesn't work

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 3):

> I want to: import { Lib1Module } from 'lib1' in
>   lib2/src/lib/lib2.module.ts
>
> And and it can't find it.

Based on this, when you import a library inside your module it'll search for it in  same directory inside node_modules.

So if you want to include  libr1 inside lib2 you should go to lib2 directory and install lib1 inside that one.

I hope this help you, If it isn't your answer tell me more about your problem

Comment: True. It searches in node_modules. I'm referring here to `ng generate library lib1`. It's in Angular6 to make local libraries that you can later publish. If I do publish them on npm and reference them, yes, works. But it's supposed to work without publishing. I want everything local

Comment: remove .ts form lib2.module.ts

Comment: Tried doesn't work. Even trying using only `public_api`. Works in dev but not in prod

Comment: what happens in prod mode?

Comment: It can't find the libraries if they are imported like this `import { Lib1Module } from 'lib1'` even though they are correctly referenced and working in dev mode. Even when they are referenced with absolute paths they cannot depend on each other.

Comment: gives any error or something? i want error message.

Comment: Just can't find the library. Like referencing any npm dependency who doesn't exist

Comment: can you put your code in github or something? It's hard to tell whats happening this way.

Comment: Did you try aliases? `"paths":  { "@lib1/*": [ "dist/lib1" ], ... }` - imports work for me within app and other libs also.